# Not able to capture summary of apriori algorithm in a dataframe

Tags: r, apriori

I am trying to capture the summary of apriori algorithm in a dataframe.
Basically I want to capture Size of 2 in a column which should have 7, size of 3 as another column and it should have 33 and so on for 4 size.
Tried using s@lengths but it does not help me to put it as a dataframe.

```
> s =summary(association_rules)
> View(s)
> s
set of 61 rules

rule length distribution (lhs + rhs):sizes
 2  3  4 
 7 33 21 

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   2.00    3.00    3.00    3.23    4.00    4.00 

summary of quality measures:
    support            confidence          lift             count     
 Min.   :0.0004016   Min.   :0.5038   Min.   :  3.462   Min.   :1291  
 1st Qu.:0.0004373   1st Qu.:0.5343   1st Qu.: 24.981   1st Qu.:1406  
 Median :0.0004672   Median :0.5745   Median : 52.934   Median :1502  
 Mean   :0.0005592   Mean   :0.5865   Mean   :110.400   Mean   :1798  
 3rd Qu.:0.0006573   3rd Qu.:0.6153   3rd Qu.: 92.320   3rd Qu.:2113  
 Max.   :0.0013792   Max.   :0.7868   Max.   :743.901   Max.   :4434  

mining info:
        data ntransactions support confidence
 order_trans       3214874   4e-04        0.5
> s@lengths
sizes
 2  3  4 
 7 33 21
```

Comment: `setNames(do.call(data.frame, as.list(s@lengths)), names(s@lengths))`?

Comment: @r2evans Sorry for asking but is there a way we can capture as a list for 2,3, 4 itemset and then create dataframe. As my intention is to capture the values for itemset with different support values and store it as a table. And sometimes it can show itemset with just 2,3 or it may have 2,3,4,5 etc.. so itemsets may vary depending on what support value I select..

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean subsetting only some of the lengths?

Comment: I mean in my dataframe, lets say there are columns for support, 2,3,4,5,6,7 but not all apriori rule will have the rule for 7 items so it should be null. and I want to do this exercise for different support values and store the numbers I get for 2,3,4,5,6,7 columns if any else null. so I think this can be handled if I capture the data for each of 2,3,4 etc in a list and then finally for all the list , I can create a dataframe.

Comment: If I understand what you said, and if `x` is the results from my first comment (`setNames(...)`), then does `Filter(Negate(anyNA), x)` do what you need?